# How do I view the logs from a TypeScript plugin?

Tags: typescript

I have a plugin configured within `tsconfig.json`.

The plugin uses `info.project.projectService.logger`

I would like to view this log when I run `tsc` or `ts-node`.

How can I see the logs outputted from a typescript plugin?

I've tried this, but I don't see anything:

```
export TSS_LOG="-logToFile true -file `pwd`/tsserver.log -level verbose"
```

Comment: `TSS_LOG="-logToFile true -file /absolute/tsserver.log -level verbose" code example` worked for me